# Update an element automatically in a website using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am still in early stages of my programming and I was thinking about creating something which does API calls after every x seconds and update my website with new content.

My intial goal is to populate a table with the content obtained from API using FOR loop (.ejs page).

Now, I want to update just those rows and columns (created from FOR loop) of my webpage after x seconds instead of refreshing my entire page.
How can I achieve this (Updating those rows and columns) ?

Consider stock market website, where it just updates the stock price, instead of entire page.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: you didn't ask for any help. What is your question?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Just updated my question.

Comment: investigate the use of Socket.io and websockets. With web socks you don't need to set a timer, you create a connection with the server and the server (your Nodejs) can push updates. Updating content is simple DOM stuff.

Comment: @RandyCasburn You still need to set a timer if you're using sockets. It just moves from being a timer you set at the client, to being one that you set at the server.

Comment: @Dan Prince - ohhhh nooo. The entire concept changes in a very good way. Can now focus on data flow and not arbitrary timers. Send when data _needs to be sent_ rather than _at an arbitrary time at which data may be exactly the same_

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yeah. I agree...but you still need a timer. The asker is pulling data from an API.

Comment: @DanPrince -  Expand your thinking a bit - the OP thinks of the API as the data source because that is the way new programmers are taught to think. The OP will discover the _reason_ he is polling the API has to do with data that changes. It is that change that drives the _need_ to poll the API when thinking about it from the UI perspective. Since the client doesn't know _when_ the data changes, the only solution is to poll the server periodically. It is much nicer for the server to send the data to the client as a normal part of its processing (update DB, record state, notify clients, etc.)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I did initial understanding of socket.io (socket.io -client here). I am using a socket connection by coincap inside my node/express (I know I should do it in external app). 

Now,  I have declared the connection out of any routes in global scope and passed the data obtained to my `app.get` landing page. The problem is that it still doesn't update the data by itself. 

How do I changed the data on my `.ejs` file by itself? @DanPrince Can you also review my comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most popular way to solve this problem is to store the data you obtain from the other API in your database, then create an endpoint that serves the most recent version of that data as JSON.

Then at the client side, you make periodic requests to the server to fetch the content and updates a part of the page to show the newest data available.

This could be as simple as:

```
// server side (if you use express)

app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
  database.getMostRecentEntry()
    .then(data => res.json(data))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).end());
});


// client side

function fetchMostRecentData() {
  fetch("/data")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => updateView(data))
    .catch(err => showError(err));
}

function updateView(data) {
  let container = document.getElementById("app");

  container.innerHTML = `
    <tr>
      <td>${data.name}</td>
      <td>${data.value}</td>
    </tr>
  `;
}

function showError(err) {
  console.error(err);
  alert("Something went wrong");
}

// call fetchMostRecentData once every 10s
setInterval(fetchMostRecentData, 10000);
```

Now, this isn't a very robust solution and there are some fairly serious security problems, but it's a starting point.

From here, you should look into using a frontend framework (rather than updating `innerHTML` yourself). You could also look at using websockets, rather than serving the data through a HTTP endpoint.

Comment: Don't need AJAX here. WebSockets and allow the server to push.

Comment: @RandyCasburn For someone who's still learning to program, sockets are overkill. They're harder to debug, harder to scale, and harder to setup.

Comment: Chicken! JK - I prefer to not downplay a person's aptitude based upon other's inability.

Comment: @RandyCasburn No one's aptitude is being downplayed. Learning is an incremental process—which is why I mentioned sockets at the end of my answer. I just prefer not to intimidate new programmers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into using [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) in combination with node.js to build your website. Then using [ajax](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/) inside your html to accomplish the rest api call updates.

Comment: Don't need AJAX here. WebSockets and allow the server to push.

Comment: AJAX is much simpler for a beginner imo

Comment: Chicken! JK - I prefer to not downplay a person's aptitude based upon other's inability.